# Angular $resource call not delivering complete data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

Can someone tell me why I'm getting the following:

Inside my controller I'm doing a normal call to an API using the Angular resource directive.

```
$scope.weatherAPI = $resource('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily', {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}, {get: {method: 'JSONP'}});
$scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI.get({ q: $scope.city, cnt: 4, APPID: 'xxxxxx' });
```

And printing the results to the console.

```
console.log($scope.weatherResult);
console.log($scope.weatherResult.city)

console.log("scope weatherResult " + $scope.weatherResult);
console.log("scope weatherResult.list: " + $scope.weatherResult.list);
console.log("scope weatherResult.city: " + $scope.weatherResult.city);
```

But here is the result. As you can see even though the objects are coming thru with `$scope.weatherResult` when I try and target one of its properties I get `undefined`, and hence am unable to use that data.

[image: the results from the console]

Comment: the return result is a promise object, you shouldn't try to retrieve data from the properties. Just check the examples on the doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Docs:

> It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data

-- [AngularJS $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Use the `.then` method of `$promise` property of the `$resource` object to supply a function to the `$q` service that will wait for the data to resolve.

```
$scope.weatherAPI = $resource('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily', {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}, {get: {method: 'JSONP'}});
$scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI.get({ q: $scope.city, cnt: 4, APPID: 'xxxxxx' });

$scope.weatherResult.$promise.then (function onFulfilled(data) {
    console.log(data);          
    console.log(data.city);

    console.log("scope weatherResult " + $scope.weatherResult);
    console.log("scope weatherResult.list: " + $scope.weatherResult.list);
    console.log("scope weatherResult.city: " + $scope.weatherResult.city);
});
```

Comment: Yup. That's what I was forgetting. Thx.